# multiple curves intersecting one master line

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, vectorization

Assuming I have a set of lines/curves and want to find at once where each one intersects with a selected one. Is it possible to vectorize this operation in matlab assuming I now all the equations that define the lines/curves?

lines to intersect with:

```
y_i=m_i*x+b_i; % i integer
```

master line

```
y=M*x+B;
```

Like in the figure I show.
[image]
I know I can do this one to one by:

```
M*x_inter+B=m_i*x_inter+b_i;
y_inter=M*x_inter+B;
```

and then put this in a for loop, But since the actual use of this is against hundreds of lines it would be more efficient to vectorize the operation.

Comment: Be careful with premature optimization. Implement it in a loop. If it turns out too slow for whatever requirements you have, try to figure out how to speed it up. Chances are, the loop code will be plenty of fast. You don't need to be scared of loops in MATLAB any more. Slow loops are in the past now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join all your m_i and b_i in column vectors and then solve it at once. Lets say you have 3 lines:

```
nlines = 3;
Bcol = ones(nlines ,1)*B; %your B value put into a column
Mcol = ones(nlines ,1)*M;

x_inter = (b - Bcol)./( Mcol - m); %this b contains all your b_i values, the same for m
y_inter = Mcol .*x_inter + Bcol
```

Obviously `x_inter` and `y_inter` wil be arrays and not single values